# How to run html file on port 8080 through vs code

Tags: html, visual-studio-code

I am trying to run my html file on port 8080 through command 'http-server' but the terminal keeps saying 'command not found'.

I have tried solving this through 'npx http-server' and 'npm install -g http-server' but then I'm told that the 'npx' and 'npm' commands cannot be found as well.

Comment: Do you have [node.js](https://nodejs.org/en/) installed?

Comment: Install [this](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ritwickdey.LiveServer) extension. You can then right-click the HTML file and click 'Open Live Server'.

Comment: you can use SimpleHTTPServer module in Python to serve static content

Answer (score -1, accepted):

hello friends please make sure you install node js correctly and maybe this article could help

1. try node -v for check node is install or not
2. try npm -v for check npm is install or not

**NOTE if you are using windows please make sure to add PATH**

how to add PATH in windows

1. search 'Environment Variables' on global search
2. Choose “Edit system environment variables”.
3. Click “Environment Variables” in the “Advanced” tab.
4. In the “System Variables” box, search for Path and edit it to include the path C:\Program Files\nodejs. If you don’t see it there click “New” then add this path. (Note: Depending on your version you may just need to edit and append this path to what’s there by prefixing it with a semicolon. You’ll see the other paths there are also separated by semicolons).

**If you are using linux it could be the permission issues**

1. sudo chown -R $(whoami):admin /usr/local/lib/node_modules/

https://linuxhint.com/npm-command-not-found/

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it is there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you are linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](/help/deleted-answers)